# Spark History server stuck loading due to Jquery error

Tags: docker, apache-spark

My spark history server is failing to load because of this jquery error below.

```
   Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size 
exceeded
    at Function.map (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.map (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at la (jquery.dataTables.1.10.4.min.js:14)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.1.10.4.min.js:92)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.p [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.1.10.4.min.js:82)
    at m.fn.init.O.g.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.1.10.4.min.js:157)
    at Object.success (historypage.js:197)
    at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
```

Here is a screen shot.
[image]

I have already increased SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY to 20G and I am using 50% CPU on my machine.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many logs.  I duplicated my logs to another folder and then turned on the history server's cleaner service.  Once the number of logs was greatly reduced, the UI started to work.